# How to redirect to external link in Angular?

Tags: angular, routes

I need to set external link to my Facebook account

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{socialFacebook.url}}">
      <mat-icon class='icons-svg' svgIcon="facebook-icon" ></mat-icon>
</a>
```

url: facebook.com/Myuseraccount
But when I try navigate to this url it redirect me to this : http://localhost:4200/facebook.com/nikita.iliciov.5 with localhost:4200 in front of my url

I try to set my code like this   `<a target="_blank" href="https://{{socialMedia.url}}">` with https in front of url but when I put my Url it looks like https://https//www.facebook.com/Myuseraccount, with double of https

How I can fix it ?

Comment: Whats the string stored in socialMedia.url?

Answer (score 0):

Try using property binding :

```
<a target="_blank" [href]="socialFacebook.url">
      <mat-icon class='icons-svg' svgIcon="facebook-icon" ></mat-icon>
</a>
```

and make sure your url starts with https or http

**socialFacebook.url** = https//www.facebook.com/Myuseraccount

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you missed the `:` after the protocol of your socialFacebook.url attribute. Then the URL is appended to the actual URL.

If you add a protocol correctly it well be seen as a own single URL.